# Firefox random glitches on screen

Tags: 20.04, firefox, snap

After a tab crash, my firefox started glitching. I tried rebooting and removing and reinstalling firefox's snap.

[image]

My Ubuntu is 20.04 and Firefox 85.0.

Random glitches appear on random places of the screen and then disappear when I move the mouse. They don't appear on print screens so I took a photo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issues. Upgrading to 20.10 fixed them.
Alternatively you might want to try the solutions mentioned [under this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/knzbm5/graphical_issues_since_update_to_840/)

- Set `gfx.webrender.force-disabled` to `true` in `about:config` and restart Firefox.

or

- Set the environment variables MOZ_X11_EGL=1

Comment: thanks, it works. Gonna wait a little more before accepting, maybe they fix the bug